# Rename dictionary key with for loop in Python 3.7

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large dataframe with many variable names over 32 characters. As I want to export the df to STATA which has a limit of 32 characters per variable name, I need to modify the variable names in the df and the associated dictionary containing the same variable names and their labels. I need help with the latter.

As I have many variables that start with the same name, I thought of modifying them through a for loop.

Consider the following variable names:

- variable_name_is_too_long_1
- variable_name_is_too_long_50

Desired output:

- variable_is_too_long_1
- variable_is_too_long_50

What I did:

```
for i in [col for col in df if col.startswith('variable_name_')]:
    df.rename(columns={i:i.replace('_name','',1)},inplace=True)
    dict_labels[i.replace('_name','',1)] = dict_labels.pop(i)
```

The columns are renamed correctly. However, nothing happens to the dictionary dict_labels (no error is given) and I can't explain it as inputs seem correct. 
Any other more efficient way is welcome!
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
for i in [col for col in df if col.startswith('variable_name_')]:
    df.rename(columns={i:i.replace('_name','',1)},inplace=True)
    aux = i.replace('_name','',1)
    dict_label[aux] = dict_label.pop(i)
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked with dict_label.pop(i) instead of dict_label[i]. I don't understand however why my original code didn't work, it seems the same to me, you just stored  i.replace('_name','',1) in aux and used aux instead!

Answer (score 1):

```
rename_labels = {col: col.replace("name_", "") for col in list(df.columns) if col.startswith("variable_name_")}

df.rename(columns = rename_labels, inplace = True)

dict_labels = {v: k for k, v in rename_labels.items()}
```

Comment: first I am making a dict in which key will be long name and value will be short name, only for those columns which starts with variable_name, then passing this dict to rename function. after that I reverse key value of dict to get actual labels from changed labels.